# Message is truncated when message size exceeeds maximum size limit

Tags: azureservicebus

In azure service buses if a message exceeds the maximum bus size of 256 KB will the message be truncated and sent to it's destination?

When i send a list of around 10000 strings the  message is sent to its destination but the list is truncated and only contains 1000 items

Comment: As Sean mentioned, messages are treated as opaque.  Neither the Service Bus client nor service will change your data.   If this is the behavior that you're seeing, please help us understand your scenario better by showing us the code that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus will not mutate your payload. Instead, a message that is too big will be rejected and an exception will be thrown.

For example, in .NET SDK a [`MessageSizeExceededException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesizeexceededexception?view=azure-dotnet) is thrown when a message exceeds the maximum size.

Instead of sending all 10K strings as a single message, you could batch your payload to ensure the maximum size is respected. [`ServiceBusMessageBatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?) is specifically designed for that.

Alternatively, there's a Premium tier to accomodate large messages requirement.